# ROR: has many relationships help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am new to rails and i want to get some help regarding has many relationships.

I included the full calendar app from https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar into my new application.

I have a user model. I want all the users to have a one calendar each. Right now the calendar is same for all users.

I tried:

#### in user.rb

```
...
belongs_to :events
```

#### in events.rb

```
has_many :users
```

This did not work.

I did the same by creating calendar.rb but it still did not work

Any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "did not work" part. How is it broken?

Comment: The way you describe it the logical thing would be to have User has_many events and event belongs_to user. Please specify what didn't work though.

Comment: More so, did you include this relationship in your `schema`?  E.g. if you look at `schema.rb`, you should have `event_id` in the "users" table.  If not, that's a good starting point (adding a migration for this).

Comment: well, what i meant with "did not work" part is that the calendar is still common for all users. @ghayes i do not have event_id in schema.rb. I will look into how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: @amunds: I realized that after posting the question but still the calendar is same for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
 a little bit more carefully.

I guess what you probably want is Event and User instances to connect with each other using `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`

After that, implementing a business logic where user attends to many events or an event has many users (attenders) is easy - I guess that is what you want, because you're bit unclear in your post. And a calendar is just a nice way to display events for a particular user.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the calendar plugin works, but for getting events that only belongs to a user you need to take advantage of the associations. If you are using one of the common authentication gems you could do current_user.events to get all events that belongs_to that user.

Answer (score -1):

In your `users`table you have to create an new column `event_id` so you can do this association with no problem.

but I guess it should be in the invert order, a User should have one or more events and a event should belong to a User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Doing this, in your events table you should add a column `user_id`